# XMLHttpRequest Sending GET Request When Opening with POST

Tags: javascript

I am writing a basic function on my webpage, to POST data to another page on my webserver, however whenever I submit using this function, the server reports having received a GET request with no form data.

Unfortunately, I am completely at a loss when it comes to sorting this out, as I have no clue what is causing it.

```
function submit_function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("username", "username");
    fd.append("password", "password");

    req.open("POST", "/auth/login", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send(fd);

    return false;
}
```

Any help or insight at all is appreciated, it is getting late and there is a good chance I'm missing something obvious.

Issue was caused by a form submission interfering with the request, because it was nested as such.

```
document.getElementById("formid").onsubmit = function(e){ submit(e); }
```

Comment: The usual reason for this is that your code is triggered by a form submission, and youre not cancelling the form submission, so the browser sends the form (as a GET, apparently there's no `type="POST"` on the form element) and the ajax call never actually runs. The code above is fine, other than the completely-unnecessary check to see if `XMLHttpRequest` exists (you're using `FormData`, so you know that `XMLHttpRequest` will also exist, no need for the `ActiveXObject` fallback; and in any case, only truly antiquated browsers don't have it natively).

Comment: While it is in a form submission, I call preventDefault and return false, and the page isn't reloaded. I'll look further into this though, thank you. Also, appreciate the feedback on the ActiveX portion, guess it is a bit of an old habit I didn't lose when I started using newer tech.

Comment: (There's nothing here specific to [tag:html5] or [tag:ecmascript-6], I've removed the irrelevant tags.)

Comment: Old habits die hard, don't they? :-)

Comment: Ah, I see what happened, thank you. At some point I nested the cancelling function in another in order to prepend another function. The help was much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I'm glad that was it! Probably no point in my posting an answer for you to accept, this is probably too specific to your situation. I suggest just deleting the question. Happy coding!

Comment: Actually, no, this is a really pure, uncluttered example. Perhaps you could add your form markup (well, the relevant parts) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for this is that your code is triggered by a form submission, and you're not cancelling the form submission, so the browser sends the form (as a GET, apparently there's no `type="POST"` on the form element) and that prevents the ajax call from actually being made (even if your code runs to start it, tearing down the page to replace it with the result of the form submission prevents it from getting very far). Just ensure you're preventing the form submission (`event.preventDefault()`).

Comment: So, though this definitely helped, and seemed to be an issue in its own right, the issue persists after fixing this, even after removing the form submit button entirely.

Comment: In that case, best to un-tick the "answered" checkmark and update the question with an [mcve].